# Kill independent python thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have to build a python application which will SSH into two Cisco IOS routers and configure BGP on them. For SSH I'm using the Netmiko module. The BGP configuration is stored in a .txt file which my code will parse.

I have implemented threading to configure both devices simultaneously. However, I am trying to implement a code where if one thread is terminated suddenly [say unable to SSH into one device] the other thread should be killed. NOTE: The two threads are independent of each other.

t1 >> threading connecting to Router1
 t2 >> threading connecting to Router2

```
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
if (t1.isAlive() and t2.isAlive()):
    t1.join(0)
    t2.join(0)
```

However, this code is not working for me. I did go through some posts here but all of them are on subprocess threads. 
Can someone please help me.

Comment: Since you're `join`ing both background threads, your main thread will not stop until both threads have finished. Have you tried checking if the background threads are alive in a loop with `sleep`?

Comment: Mikhail, I am new to python programming and I really don't understand what u mean by 'background thread'. There is no main thread which invokes threads t1 and t2. Rather the two threads are independent.